# Icon not shown in launcher

Tags: android, icons

My icon is not shown in the launcher and I can't figure out where the problem could be.
This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.giacomopancaldi.imagesender">
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the use
r's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
/>
<application
android:name=".AppGlobal"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="Image Sender"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
</activity>
<activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
<activity android:name=".loginActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.LOGIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".UploadActivity" />
<activity android:name=".ViewImageActivity"></activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I've put all the sizes for my `ic_launcher` (hdpi, xxhdpi, etc.), but it still doesn't work.

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: without any launcher icon or the default one is showing?

Comment: try to uninstall and install again!!

Comment: Make sure you put it in "mipmap" folders and not "drawable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOGIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Replace with

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case it was not showing because i decide to simplify by joining 2 intent-filter elements:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

With this declaration in the manifest, the app is installed but the app icon is not installed, regardless application attributes `icon` and `roundicon` are correct or not.

**Action Main need to be on its own xml element like this:**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: This is so important. The intent-filter for the "MAIN" and "LAUNCHER" stuff needs to stand alone. It is not very clear in most tutorials and an easy bug to encounter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have your icons in the `mipmap` folder like this:

[image: mipmap]

Also I suggest you use Image Asset to import your icon:

> File -> new -> Image Asset

[image: image asset]

Comment: as I specified in my question, I've already got all the correct sizes of my icon. anyway, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 2):

delete or replace mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder

Comment: This one was the answer for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but maybe your `ic_launcher` resource was placed in `drawable` directory rather than `mipmap`.

Make sure you really have your `ic_launcher` resource at the right path. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. The Intent of your Launcher Activity should be named
   `android.intent.action.MAIN`

**Replace** `<action android:name="android.intent.action.LOGIN" />`

**with** `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`

2. Make sure you hava a icon named `ic_launcher.png` in your mipmap
   folder.
3. If that doesn't work clean your project build and uninstall any
   existing version of your app from your phone/emulator and reinstall
   the new version.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it was a problem with the `intent-filter`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if you create Image Asset for Adaptive Icons you need to set buildToolsVersion in your app's build.gradle to at least 26.0.0